# Oculus Rift Touch controller input not working for some users in Unity 3D

Tags: unity, oculus

I am working on a music based game that supports both Oculus Rift (touch controllers), HTC Vive and also no VR. Everything is working fine, but the past few days I have been stuck with 1 bug and I don't know what the cause is.

In my game I have a pause setting. This works properly for all 3 play modes. My colleague/friend that I work together with also has Oculus Rift with the touch controllers and somehow for him the buttons A, B, X and Y aren't working. The game doesn't get an input signal. In the Oculus app the input is working so it is only bugged in the game and not the hardware itself. From my side the game does get an input signal from the said buttons. Same code, same scenario. The only difference between our setups is that he has windows 7 and I have windows 10. He did a full reinstall with hotfixes, but the bug still persists.

I am using the touch mapping specified in the unity documents: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OculusControllers.html
Once again I have no issues and everything works correctly on my end. On his end however only the buttons X, Y, A and B aren't working. I tested this with simple objects being highlighted when the buttons are pressed as the simplest most basic visual testing method. He gets no error or whatsoever. Log file is clean as well. I have absolutely no idea about what I am doing wrong.

If both our controllers input didn't get recognized by the game then I'd understand that the buttons might not have been mapped properly. But for one person it works and for the other it doesn't. Now the other strange thing is that the other buttons are working on his end such as the triggers and thumb-sticks. And yes I have validated that both our game clients are the exact same version.

I have tried to do some research on my own, but I couldn't find working fixes, since on my end everything is working properly (including the fixes), but not on his end when it comes to those specific 4 buttons.

Update:
He upgraded to windows 10 and it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly Oculus Rift on Windows 7 doesn't work properly. The hotfixes make it seem to function correctly, but a lot drivers aren't configured correctly.

After he installed Windows 10 we did a full clean instal of Oculus Rift on Windows 10 and the issue no longer existed.

For future people having similar issues, Oculus Rift only works properly on Windows 10 and not on the older versions of Windows.